# uinavigation controller segue within static table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating an app that has a static uitableview with three large cells. I would like each cell to have its own navigation controller that operates within the cell. When I associate a navigation controller with a cell (via edit/embed in/navigation controller) I get a situation where a segue from a table cell results in the entire tableview being replaced rather than the cell view. Is there a way (ideally via storyboards) that in merely replace the view controller within the cell. It is not a hard requirement that the table be static.
Thanks.

Comment: Only view controllers can be embedded in a navigation controller, so what I think you're trying to do isn't possible. Maybe edit your question to say what you're trying to accomplish. What's in the cell now, what do you want to change it to?

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. rethink your UI flow to avoid putting a UINavigationController inside a UITableViewCell.  As you've seen, a navigation controller expects to be the top controller in a window's hierarchy and will install itself to be such,
2. implement your own navigation-controller-like functionality as a custom UITableViewCell.

#1 really is the option you should take.

Consider using a UITabBarController with three tabs, one for each of the UINavigationControllers of your table cells.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I want to use the TableView to provide fixed regions of the display which vary at different times. The top region would hold a CollectionView and selecting a cell yields a different CollectionView. The middle region would be similar and the bottom would be static and visible always. Obviously I'll need to rethink using a TableView as my organizing mechanism.